# rails6 指定したレコードのIDと照合したいIDを一致させたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

問題モデルの指定したレコードとカラムをランダムにビューに表示し、テキストエリアに答えを入力した後に、先程指定したレコードの答えカラムと入力した答えを照合することで、正解か不正解をフラッシュメッセージを出すようにしたいです。

現在、指定したレコードとカラムをランダムにビューに表示し、テキストエリアに答えを入力ができますが、照合しようとすると、"Couldn't find Problem without an ID" というエラーが出ます。

ランダムに表示したレコードのidと照合しようしたidが一致しなくて困っています。
どうかご教授願います。

こちらがコードになります。

controller

```
class ProblemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_action :correct_user, only: %i[edit update]

  def show
    @problem = Problem.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @problem = Problem.new
  end

  def create
    @problem = current_user.problems.build(problem_params)
    @problem.picture.attach(params[:problem][:picture])
    if @problem.save
      flash[:success] = '問題が作成されました！'
      redirect_to problem_path(@problem)
    else
      render 'problems/new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @problem = Problem.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @problem = Problem.find(params[:id])
    if @problem.update(problem_params)
      flash[:succcess] = '問題情報が更新されました！'
      redirect_to @problem
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @problem = Problem.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.admin? || current_user?(@problem.user)
      @problem.destroy
      flash[:success] = '問題が削除されました'
      redirect_to request.referer == user_url(@problem.user) ? user_url(@problem.user) : root_url
    else
      flash[:danger] = '別アカウントの問題は削除できません'
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def random
    @problem = Problem.offset( rand(Problem.count)).take
  end

  def answer
    @problem = Problem.find(params[:id])
  
    if @problem.answer == params[:problem][:answer]
      flash.now[:notice] = "当たり"
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "はずれ"
    end
    
    render :random
  end

  private

    def problem_params
      params.require(:problem).permit(:study_type, :title, :explanation_text, :problem_text, :answer, :problem_explanation, :taget_age, :reference, :picture)
    end

    def correct_user
      # 現在のユーザーが更新対象の問題を保有しているかどうか確認
      @problem = current_user.problems.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @problem.nil?
    end
end
```

view

```
<% provide(:title, "問題出題") %>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <%= form_with model: @problem, url: {controller: 'problems', action: 'answer'} do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
        <div><%= @problem.study_type %></div><br>
        <div><%= @problem.explanation_text %></div><br>
        <div><%= @problem.problem_text %></div><br>
        <%= f.text_field :answer, value: "" %>
        <%= f.submit "回答", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <%= link_to "次の問題へ", problems_random_path%>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

routes

```
  get "/problems/random", to: "problems#random"
  patch '/problems/random', to: 'problems#answer'
  resources :problems
```

Answer (score 0):

pathに@problemのidが入っていないことが原因かと思います
以下のようにしてpathにidを含めればviewの `<%= f.hidden_field :id %>`も必要ありません

**route.rb**

```rb
resources :problems do
  get :random, on: :collection
  patch :random, to: 'problems#answer', on: :member
end
```

**rails routes 結果**

```
                                                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                        Controller#Action
                                         random_problems GET    /problems/random(.:format)                                                                         problems#random
                                          random_problem PATCH  /problems/:id/random(.:format)                                                                     problems#answer
                                                problems GET    /problems(.:format)                                                                                problems#index
                                                         POST   /problems(.:format)                                                                                problems#create
                                             new_problem GET    /problems/new(.:format)                                                                            problems#new
                                            edit_problem GET    /problems/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                       problems#edit
                                                 problem GET    /problems/:id(.:format)                                                                            problems#show
                                                         PATCH  /problems/:id(.:format)                                                                            problems#update
                                                         PUT    /problems/:id(.:format)                                                                            problems#update
                                                         DELETE /problems/:id(.:format)                                                                            problems#destroy
```

**view**

```
<%= form_with model: @problem, url: random_problem_path(@problem), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

参考
https://railsguides.jp/routing.html